# How to get Webtop Drl of a document via .net application?

Tags: documentum, emc, webtop

Is it possible to retrieve drl ex:https://host:port /ewebtop/drl/objectId/0900a58e80970f7b of document via .net application?.So that when users clicks on this link they can be able to edit the document and when they close the document the document should be autosaved onto documentum.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: a link is a link. What you decide to do with it I u to you. Default handler in browser will just redirect you to webtop application. If you have SSO you can have the document opened for edit. There are some extra arguments that can be provided (view/edit).
The object id is the only varying part of the URL, so you can easily construct this in code.

Secondly: what is your goal? There is no way to make the document upload itself into Documentum repo. You can write a plugin for every application to handle that, but it seems like a big task - especially dealing with security.

The problem is that upon check-in, user must provide some information - at least about the new version number...

If you're building a thick client in .net I would go with DFS - that's the only real option here.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.let me explain you clearly what I need to do.Currently inorder to edit a document users need to download the document then edit and then upload.But now my task is to allow the user to edit document without downloading it (for this reason I thought if I can get the Drl of the document.so as soon as user clicks on that drl he can edit document ).I am using DFS.Is there any api which helps to get the drl of the document or writing the code inorder to construct the drl is the only option?